# css how to create 2 horizontal lines next to centered circle?

Tags: html, css

css how to create 2 horizontal lines next to centered circle?

I want to connect the boxes that will be next to each other with their positions centered, how can I do this?

```css
#login {
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.elips {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
  padding: red 2rem;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
  <div id="login">
      <div class="elips"></div>
      <div><pre>-----
  -----<pre>
      </div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`dashed border style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) for the middle div. You need not use text for it.

```css
#login {
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.elips {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
  padding: red 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.dashed-lines {
  border: 2px dashed black; 
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  border-left: transparent; 
  border-right: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <div class="elips"></div>
  <div class="dashed-lines"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```